# How can i maintain update of a column while performing operation on two different tables simultaneously

Tags: mysql

I have a table regarding master product details in which there is a (initial)quantity column and another table having column sold_quantity. now i want a column in master table where this column have result of (initial) quantity - sold_quantity...and result to be updated on every transaction.

Comment: Got some code to add?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for triggers. This might be helpful http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html